# PopupWindow doesn't respond to drag and drop events

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-popupwindow

I have a menu icon in my application. When I drag and drop something on it, it will show a popup. I need to extend my drag and drop to this `PopupWindow`.

I am doing this as below.

**Created a PopupWindow as shown**

```
View popupView = View.inflate(anchorView.getContext(), R.layout.layout_popup, null);

PopupWindow popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**And setting the dragListener as shown**

```
popupView.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {



                    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        Log.d("Drag", "ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                        Log.d("Drag", "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.d("Drag", "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        Log.d("Drag", "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.d("Drag", "ACTION_DROP");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Below video shows what I want to achieve.

[image]

But the popupView is not responding to any drag events. I also tried using the `DialogFragment`, but it didn't help either.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PopupWindow` will [add the `View` on `WindowManager` instance](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#L1378), and not to the current layout. Whereas [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#DragDropLifecycle) it is specified:

> The system sends a drag event with action type **ACTION_DRAG_STARTED** to the drag event listeners for all the View objects **in the current layout**.

Pay attention to bolded "**in the current layout**". The content view of `PopupWindow` is not considered to be in the current layout, that's why those events are not dispatched to `PopupWindow`'s content view.

As a workaround you can add a `View` with same coordinates to the current layout, which will act as a ghost of `PopupWindow`, and listen for drag events for this `View`.

---

### Implementation

Add the *ghost view* to the layout:

```
<include android:id="@+id/ghost"
         layout="@layout/layout_popup"/>
```

Setup the *ghost view* from `onCreate()`:

```
    private void setupGhostView() {
        ghost = findViewById(R.id.ghost);
        ghost.setAlpha(0.0f);
        ghost.findViewById(R.id.txt_append).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        ghost.findViewById(R.id.txt_replace).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

We do **not** want *ghost view* to be visible, that's why we set it's alpha to zero.

Then we setup the `PopupWindow` having anchor view:

```
    private void preparePopup(View anchorView) {
        final View popupView = View.inflate(anchorView.getContext(), R.layout.layout_popup, null);
        popupView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popupWindow.setTouchable(false);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                popupView.getMeasuredWidth(), popupView.getMeasuredHeight());
        params.gravity = Gravity.END;
        ghost.setLayoutParams(params);
        ghost.invalidate();
        ghost.requestLayout();
    }
```

We need to perform `setTouchable(false)`, otherwise `PopupWindow` will consume touch events. Also, we set *ghost view*'s location exactly at the position where `PopupWindow` will be displayed.

Then we show and dismiss `PopupWindow` on appropriate drag events:

```
    menuView.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();
            switch (dragEvent) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

### Result

[image]

A pull request [is opened](https://github.com/heyjii/DragNDropSample/pull/1) in your repo with abovementioned functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I need is different from what you have proposed. I have added a gif to define it better.  Thanks again for your edits as well.

Comment: If I understand correct, you are dragging a `Button`, not a `PopupWindow`. Why would you expect drag callbacks to be fired for `PopupWindow`? You are **not** dragging `PopupWindow`, right?

Comment: Yes I am not dragging PopupWindow... I need to get the dropevent within the PopupWindow.

Comment: According the documentation, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDragAndDrop(android.content.ClipData, android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder, java.lang.Object, int), It says "Once the system has the drag shadow, it begins the drag and drop operation by sending drag events to all the View objects in your application that are currently visible."... That means it can be dropped to views which is visible when the drag started...

Comment: Perform `contentView.dispatchDragEvent(dragEvent);` whenever `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` happens while dragging your button.

Comment: contentView.dispatchDragEvent(dragEvent) simply dispacthing the dragEvents without considering whether it above the popupwindow or not... Anyway thanks for your suggestion ... I am looking for a solution based on that...

Comment: If you post a simple project with the setup you demonstrated in the gif, I'll have a look on it.

Comment: You can clone the sample project from here
https://github.com/heyjii/DragNDropSample.git

Comment: Thanks for spending some time on this.. Although this works in sample application, I couldn't manage to do this in my actual project since in there activity view itself is supposed to be listening to dragevents. Anyway I really thankful for your effort. Hope I can use this some other way. :)

Comment: You can keep a boolean, which will indicate you whether your activity's view should handle the drag event. When showing and dismissing `PopupWindow` change boolean value respectfully.

Comment: I can't disable the activity's dragListener as what I am dropping is acceptable by that view as well... Anyway I have changed implementation with menu icons instead of Popwindow. That is pretty simple and elegant.